# Receiving HTML request from Bootstrap <button>

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter-bootstrap

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="btn-group col-sm-3">
        <button id="typeSelect" type="button" name="reportType" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            People <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>
                ...
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" name="name" value="{{name}}" onblur="isEmpty(this)">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have two inputs in my form and I am trying to get the input in my Python code.

```
    report_type = self.request.get('reportType')
    name = self.request.get('name')
```

*name* is working correctly, but *report_type* will always be None.
What is the correct way to retrieve the selection in a button (Bootstrap)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [button element specifications](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#the-button-element):

> *A button (and its value) is only included in the form submission if the button itself was used to initiate the form submission.*

You will have to find another way to pass the value of the button. You could, for example, store the value in a hidden field.